# How to get timezone from properties in CultureInfo

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, timezone

I have a string, which contains a timestamp *(`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`)*. I can create a `CultureInfo` object based on other information I get. Therefore I know which country the timestamp is in. The timestamp is not in UTC/GMT.

Say the timestamp is from Indonesia *(`new CultureInfo("id-ID")`)* , meaning the string was created by code below or similar.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

That means the string contains the local time in Indonesia. I know my timezone, but I don't know how to convert the Indonesian time to UTC/GMT, so I can use the UTC/GMT object in `TimeZoneInfo`. My own timezone may or may not be in the same timezone.

Is there anywhere, this information is connected?

`CultureInfo` has a lot of properties, surely some of them can be used to get timezone, somwhere?

I might add that I find the entire system very confusing, so I could be way off in how I think things works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: No

Long Answer:  This is a 1 to many relationship between culture and timezone.  For example:
en-US - English, American contains 6 timezones...  so how would you get from en-US to Eastern Daylight time?  ... and how do you get the daylight savings time offsets?

It's a confusing cultural conundrum (wow, try saying that 5 times fast) that is not easily solvable with the CLR.

Comment: No I noticed pretty much immediately that this would be a challenge.

I've googled about abit, and I found this wiki [Time zones by country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zones_by_country). There are not that many countries with that many timezones. *Australia, Brazil, Canada, France, Indonesia (heh), Mexico, New Zealand, Russia (!), UK, USA +-*

Now using that as a datasource, and defaulting to the capital city's timezone for the countries with lots of tz, It goes along way.

Just airing my idea here.